# LimitInternalRecursion Error on PHP project

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I am trying to install an opensource project called by UVDesk, here is project github page: https://github.com/uvdesk

After Completing installation steps, UVDesk app getting internal server error called by *"Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."*

It's about many redirection and I guess there is a infinite loop because of .htaccess. So I created a index.php file in public folder, index.php file opened

Preconditions

1. Digital Ocean Droplet with Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64
2. Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
3. Running PHP version: PHP 8.0-fpm

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
```

When I delete index.php file, error raising again.

I am not familiar with PHP, Linux and Apache world.

Thanks!

Comment: Your rules assume there is an `index.php` in your site root directory.

Comment: What is your directory structure? Where is the `.htaccess` file located? "So I created a index.php file in public folder, index.php file opened" - So, the `.htaccess` file is located in the `public` folder? Your `.htaccess` file requires an `index.php` file (a _front-controller_) in the same directory (otherwise you'll get an infinite rewrite-loop, hence the 500 error). "When I delete index.php file, error raising again." - so, what is the question?

Comment: _Aside:_ "LimitInternalRecursion Error" - That's not the "error", that is a suggested solution (although increasing the value of `LimitInternalRecursion` is very rarely the solution). The _error_ is the "internal rewrite loop".